# Unhandled Rejection with FieldValue.arrayUnion()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on making a social media clone and when I'm trying to follow another profile I'm getting thrown an error. When I try to console.log("follow user") it'll work just fine but when I change it to onClick={handleFollowUser} it'll throw an error saying that something is undefined.

You can view the specific error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkFlU.jpg

The error I get is:

> Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document users/pX1fay49L6fLiYwnzIXL)

```
  async function handleFollowUser() {
    setFollowed(true);
    await updateLoggedInUserFollowing(loggedInUserDocId, profileId, false);
    await updateFollowedUserFollowers(profileDocId, userId, false);
  }

      <button
        className="text-xs font-bold text-blue-medium"
        type="button"
        onClick={handleFollowUser}
        // onClick={console.log('Follow this user!')}
      >
        Follow
      </button>
```

```
  export async function updateLoggedInUserFollowing(
    loggedInUserDocId, // currently logged in user document id (gore's profile)
    profileId, // the user that gore requests to follow
    isFollowingProfile // true/false (am i currently following this person?)
  ) {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(loggedInUserDocId)
      .update({
        following: isFollowingProfile ? FieldValue.arrayRemove(profileId) : FieldValue.arrayUnion(profileId)
      });
  }
  
  export async function updateFollowedUserFollowers(
    profileDocId, // currently logged in user document id (gore's profile)
    loggedInUserDocId, // the user that gore requests to follow
    isFollowingProfile // true/false (am i currently following this person?)
  ) {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(profileDocId)
      .update({
        followers: isFollowingProfile
          ? FieldValue.arrayRemove(loggedInUserDocId)
          : FieldValue.arrayUnion(loggedInUserDocId)
      });
  }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both. Also: please don't delete and repost a question. The edits you made to your precious were enough to draw attention to it again.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Firebase to know which would've been relevant so I apologize for that and the repost.

Comment: No worries. For the actual problem: it seems you're trying to write `undefined` to the database, which is not supported. I can't quickly see which field it is, but if you step through the code in a debugger it should be fairly easy to find which of your variables is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@Frank van Puffelend` said, you're trying to write an undefined value to your database and this will trow an error. You can fix in several ways, one is to make Firebase ignore the undefined values. An example is:

```
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin"

const db = firestore.firestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
```